# Grails returning value from controller to gsp

Tags: grails

I have been searching on how to return an integer value from controller to the gsp. I tried using this:

```
    def test(){
        def val = 1;
        return val;
    }
```

but it does not work. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 def test(){
    def val = 1;
    [val:val]
   }
```

Comment: See [Models and Views](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews) section of the grails docs for further informations ...

Answer (score 2):

The `return` statement is used to return values from `services` to `controllers`.
If you want to pass values from the `controller` to `gsp`, use:

```
[variableNameInGSP : valueToBeReturned]
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your controller:

```
def test(){
    def v = 10
    render view:'test.gsp', model:[v:v]
   }
```

Then, access the value from your test.gsp by `"${v}"` 
Note that the `render view` is optional for test.gsp, i've written it only for demo purpose.. (i.e change the gsp filename).

Hope it helps.